# Connecting to Google Api Client - why?

Tags: google-api, android-intentservice

I'm building a location based app and want to use the [Displaying a Location Address](https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html) instructions. I saw that I need to connect to Google Api Client but I don't know 1) why, or 2) what the benefit of using **this google api connection** for fetching an address from coordinates (using intent service). 3) Can I use the intent service without connecting to Google Api...

10X